# single row subquery returns more than one row, what does it mean with my line of code

Tags: sql, oracle

What am I doing wrong exactly with this code for a school project:

```
SELECT R_number,AVG(R_capacity) 
FROM room   
GROUP BY R_number   
HAVING AVG(R_capacity)<           
(SELECT AVG(R_capacity)            
FROM room           
WHERE R_number IN             
(SELECT R_number FROM student                  
WHERE S_ID                   
BETWEEN 20190373 AND 20191145)             
GROUP BY R_number);
```

Comment: It means exactly what the error states. You need to decompose your query and check which subquery causes this error

Answer (score 1):

In your `having` clause you are comparing the average in the main part of the query with the subquery:

```
(
  SELECT AVG(R_capacity)
  FROM room
  WHERE R_number IN
  (
    SELECT R_number
    FROM student 
    WHERE S_ID
    BETWEEN 20190373 AND 20191145
  )
  GROUP BY R_number
)
```

That subquery is going to give you the average capacity for *each* ID in that range, which could be hundreds of rows. Hence the error - where Oracle is expecting the subquery to return a single row, it's returning many rows.

You presumably want a single average value across that range of IDs, so you just need to remove that second `group by` clause:

```
SELECT R_number,AVG(R_capacity)
FROM room
GROUP BY R_number
HAVING AVG(R_capacity) <
(
  SELECT AVG(R_capacity)
  FROM room
  WHERE R_number IN
  (
    SELECT R_number
    FROM student 
    WHERE S_ID
    BETWEEN 20190373 AND 20191145
  )
)
```